# How use https in mono application

Tags: linux, ssl, https, mono, monodevelop

When we develop on windows localhost application with https we assign cert to application port

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:5000 certhash=4379cdc7dca5e06ae4dc25cf1892c4111deb61f5 appid={4CD4348D-D9C7-47E6-9252-74D528FB0971}
```

But how it work on linux? I have application wrote in mono listen a 5000 port . I dont know how I can use https.

Comment: this depends on how you are hosting your program. I assume it's ASP.NET running in Mono XSP4. If this is the case you can simply add https parameters to the CLI command to run xsp4. If you're using Apache (mod mono) or Nginx you'll need to read up on how to use https with those. Which way are you hosting?

Comment: @muszeo problem is i dont want use hosting program. This is very small program for listening port. It works but without https